# VirtualBox : renaming a VDI disk causes snapshot to fail loading

Tags: virtualbox, path, snapshot

I have a machine which I installed using VirtualBox. Its VDI disk was named "Name1.vdi".

After a while, I resized it, renamed it to "Name2.vdi", moved it to another disk, and so on. But now I need to restore my snapshot.

I have this error :

```
Could not open the medium 'F:\VM\Windows Server 2012\Name1.vdi'.
VD: error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'F:\VM\Windows Server 2012\Name1.vdi' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).
```

Where can I edit a file to change the path to my disk ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.

Go to file, Virtual Media Manager.

From here, you can remove and add virtual harddrive images.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I am screwed : the UUID has been reset since I copied the original disk to another, and the snapshot was attached to the first. I think that if I reset the disk UUID to the old one it would work, but I think it would take time for something not worth it ...

Comment: Just release it. I had the same problem and was able to fix it using the virtual media manager.